# 2007 Honda Civic won't move in any gear. Loud scratching noise when put in "park"

Tags: honda, transmission, civic

Yesterday I changed the left CV-Joint of my 2007 Honda Civic. After the change, I drove the car for about 2km, and when I tried to park, I heard a loud scratching noise.

I put off the engine and started it again.
But it won't move in any gear. Not Reverse, Drive, D3, 2 or 1. None. When put in "park", it makes a loud scratching noise.

It also keeps blinking on "D" even when shifting to other gears.
The speedometer also goes up when I rev the engine, but the car won't move.
Please, what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you rechecked your work? Is the cv shaft seated?

Answer (score 0):

The flashing "D" is how these cars indicate a transmission error code - IIRC the sequence of the blinks translates to the code, I don't have the sequences to hand but given the symptoms you describe I'd put money on it being an issue with the vehicle/transmission speed sensor.

Have you got an OBD-II code reader you could use to try get the code to confirm? Or could you get someone with one to come to the car to check it?